# How to display comments from first post of the category in all posts?

Tags: wordpress, templates, comments

I want the display the comments from first post of the category only.

**Example;**

Category
- Post 1 (2 comments)
- Post 2 (1 comments)
- Post 3 (5 comments)

If I am reading the **Post 2** or **Post 3**, I should see **2 comments of the Post 1**.

How can I code this from template files?

Thanks for your helps.

Answer (score 0):

You juste have to use a WP_query ( http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query ) like this :

```
$args = array(
'cat' => 'catnumber',
'post_count' => '1'
 );

$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

The query will return you the last post of the category you want. Then you just have to use the function get_comments in your loop : http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_comments